# How to make only the image itself clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, button

I am currently making some sort of interactive map. It consists of images of 12 areas overlapping. The problem is that the image is squared, so if I click on a state next to it and it overlaps, I can't select it.

Is there a way to make only the image itself 'clickable' and not the transparent part of the image?

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your map?

Comment: Have you tried OBShapeButton.

https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

Comment: OBShapebutton is not available in swift it seems but only objective C